# Android notification repeats several times at event instead of one time

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, alarm

I want the code to execute a notification once every day at 07 *am*. I created a debug apk and installed it to see how it performs and noticed, that it actually sends a notification at about 07 *am*, but if you click on the notification and get into the app and close it afterwars, it sends a notification again. Does someone see a mistake in the code?

this is the code in the **MainActivity.java** (the notification part):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    intent_anmeldeActivity = new Intent(this, anmeldeActivity.class);
    intent_WebViewActivity = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefsEditor = prefs.edit();


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 07);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    intent_notification = new Intent(this, NotificationClass.class);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Also it sends notifications kind of randomly.

**Thanks in advance!**

**EDIT:**

```
public class NotificationClass extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    loadText loadText = new loadText();
    loadText.startAsyncTask(context);
} }
```

In AsyncTask class loadText, the class NotificationBuilding is executed in `onPostExecute`:

```
public class NotificationBuilding {

Context mContext = null;

int ID = 1;
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

public void startNotificationBuilding(Context con, String title, String text) {

    this.mContext = con;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setColor(Color.argb(255, 234, 146, 21))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setLights(Color.argb(255, 234, 146, 21), 1000, 10000)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text));

    notificationManager.notify(ID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    ID++;
} }
```

Comment: Are you launching `MainActivty` from `NotficationClass` Broadcast ?

Comment: nope, the NotificationClass starts another class with AsyncTask code

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 7:00 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 07);

       // With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
        // constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
        alarmMgr.**setInexactRepeating**(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

**Decide how precise your alarm needs to be**
    As described above, choosing the alarm type is often the first step in creating an alarm. A further distinction is how precise you need your alarm to be. For most apps, setInexactRepeating() is the right choice. When you use this method, Android synchronizes multiple inexact repeating alarms and fires them at the same time. This reduces the drain on the battery.

For the rare app that has rigid time requirements—for example, the alarm needs to fire precisely at 8:30 a.m., and every hour on the hour thereafter—use setRepeating(). But you should avoid using exact alarms if possible.

With setInexactRepeating(), you can't specify a custom interval the way you can with setRepeating(). You have to use one of the interval constants, such as INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_DAY, and so on. See AlarmManager for the complete list.

Comment: OK, thanks! But it still sends a notification every time after opening the app and closing it.

Comment: Can you post notification class in the question part